# Android xml design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android developing. Please help me how to arrange these properties in the given image?

Thanks[image]

I did in this way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_3"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dim_3"
    android:weightSum="7" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spot_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/movie_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/item"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="openMovieDetailPage"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow_32" />

    <!-- <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/movie_type"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_11" /> -->

   <!--  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/movie_rating"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_12"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal" /> -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_3"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dim_3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/movie_rating"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried in this way but all the properties are aligned vertically. But I need in the given image style.

Comment: What efforts did you do?

Comment: The way you asking this question is off-topic. read the Help section to learn how to ask questions here....

Comment: Sorry, next i am going to read help section for proper questing thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve above design with `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` easily.So
Try this layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_3"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dim_3"
     >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spot_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/movie_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spot_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/item"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="openMovieDetailPage"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow_32" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spot_title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/movie_rating"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Great Boss. it's working using Relative Great. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_3"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dim_3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spot_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/movie_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/item"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/movie_rating"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="openMovieDetailPage"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow_32" />

</LinearLayout>
```